# Jquery input array form ajax

Tags: jquery

How do i get the input array `username` values in the jQuery variable `users`?

```
    <input type='text' name='username[]' class='users' value='test1' />
    <input type='text' name='username[]' class='users' value='test2' />
    <input type='text' name='username[]' class='users' value='test3' />

<div class='submit'>Submit</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('.submit').click(function() {

            var users = 
        var dataString = 'users=' + users;

            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'users.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {


                }
            });
        });


    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). It should give you an array of the usernames.

```
var users = $('input:text.users').serialize();
```

You can be however lazy or specific with the selector: `.users`,`input.users`,`form .users` would all work, plus a few more.

For this example:

```
// users = 
username[]=test1&username[]=test2&username[]=test3
```

Which, depending on your server-side technology, will come through in the request as an array of strings for the key "username" (PHP, for example).

Answer (score 15):

```
    <script>

        $(function() {

            $('.submit').click(function() {

                // Get data as array, ['Jon', 'Mike']
                var users = $('input[name="username[]"]').map(function(){ 
                    return this.value; 
                }).get();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'users.php',
                    data: {
                        'username[]': users,
                        // other data
                    },
                    success: function() {

                    }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Not as elegant as the other solutions, but it works great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array:

```
// from inside the submit callback
var users = $(this).find('.users').map(function(i, el) {
    return el.value;
});
```

Demo (run with the console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w2RRW/

Comment: @user892134: See Intersellar's comment or the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/map/, and are you trying to get an array or URL string? Your question and code say different things.

Comment: an array, which ajax POST to users.php.

Comment: @user892134: If you want an array, then your AJAX call would use `data: { users: users }`, if you're happy with a URL string then do what you're doing now but use Cory's `serialize` approach.