# remove single item from cart using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to remove a product from cart using php. I'm able to delete the product using input and button type submit like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>" />
<button id="remove-from-cart" type="submit">delete</button>
```

I have to select each checkbox and click submit to remove product everytime. Now I want to remove item from cart using ajax without refreshing the whole page and I want to use only button or img tag instead of input tag.
This is my php code and

```
// Code for Remove a Product from Cart
if(isset($_POST['remove_code']))
 {

  if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_POST['remove_code'] as $key){
        
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }
        // echo "<script>alert('Your Cart has been Updated');</script>";
   }
 }
```

this is my ajax request

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove-from-cart", function () {
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "my-cart.php",
            type: "post",
            success: function () {
                
                
            },
        });
   });
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Hi Islam!! I want to remove product from cart using ajax without refreshing the page. Now  I'm struggling to find which php value that I've to use in ajax response to delete item.

Comment: How are you sending your data to your ajax?

Comment: using my-cart.php file. The php code mentioned above is in my-cart.php file.

Comment: How are you sending your data *from* your code *to* your file? I think you'll need to read about ajax forms if you can't understand my question.

Comment: That's where I'm struggling to use ajax. I'm new to use ajax with php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220544/discussion-between-lin-and-islam-elshobokshy).

Comment: So you need to send checkbox value which is checked to backend ?

Comment: yes swathi!! I'm sending the remove_code as data in ajax, that's the php remove function works and now I need to ajax in order to prevent page load.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856980/jquery-input-array-form-ajax) post might help.